# ¿Cómo solucionar "was not declared in this scope"?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo una duda, sobre la línea 17, dice `[Error] 'suma' was not declared in this scope`. Se que aparece cuando no se declara una variable bien o no se hace dentro de una función pero yo tengo este problema:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class repetir{
    private:
        int x, n_notas, suma, promedio;
        
    public:
        void repeticion();
        void salida_datos();
            
};

void repeticion()
{
    x=1;
    suma=0;
    while (suma<=10){
    cout<< "ingrese una nota.";
    cin>>n_notas;
    x=x+1;
}

}

void salida_datos()
{
    promedio=suma + n_notas;
    cout<< "el promedio es: "<<promedio;
    
}



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    repetir repetir1;
    repetir1.repeticion();
    repetir1.salida_datos();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Y declare la variable como int, y más tarde use suma=0 pero aun asi no compila.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que indicar que las funciones son de la clase:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class repetir {
   private:
    int x, n_notas, suma, promedio;

   public:
    void repeticion();
    void salida_datos();
};

void repetir::repeticion() {
    x = 1;
    suma = 0;
    while (suma <= 10) {
        cout << "ingrese una nota.";
        cin >> n_notas;
        x = x + 1;
    }
}

void repetir::salida_datos() {
    promedio = suma + n_notas;
    cout << "el promedio es: " << promedio;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    repetir repetir1;
    repetir1.repeticion();
    repetir1.salida_datos();

    return 0;
}
```